# Triple joins with SQL?

Tags: sql

My database represents a library. Each book is tagged with multiple things, so that one title might be tagged 'science fiction', 'short stories', and 'Russian'.

There are three tables: `books`, `tags`, and `books_tag_link`. They look like this:

**Books**

```
 ID     |     TITLE
 -----------------------------
 1      | Rendezvous With Rama
 2      | Howl and Other Poems
 3      | A Short History of Nearly Everything
```

**Tags**

```
 ID     |     TAGNAME
 -----------------------------
 1      |     science fiction
 2      |     fiction
 3      |     poetry
```

**Books_Tag_Link**

```
 BOOK     |     TAG
 -----------------------------------
 1        |     1
 1        |     2
 2        |     3
```

Hopefully you can see how that would work. The books_tag_link table has two foreign keys, and links books to tags; each book has many tags, each tag is associated with many books. I don't know if this is the *best* way to do it but it's what the OSS library program Calibre does, and that's what I'm kind of using as a reference as I study.

Now what I want to do is say "select all fiction books". But I can't quite work out the proper way to express that thought in SQL. `Select books.title where books.id = tags.id = books_tag_link.tag`... or something. I'm not sure.

Can someone help me out with a tip or explanation of what I should be doing?

I'm using SQLite at the moment but MySQL-specific advice would be fine too.

Comment: You have to connect the tables with Joins.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT b.title
FROM Books AS b
JOIN Books_Tag_Link AS bt ON b.id = bt.book
JOIN Tags AS t ON t.id = bt.tag
WHERE t.tagname = 'fiction'
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that?

```
select b.title 
from Books b join Books_Tag_Link btl on btl.BOOK=b.ID
join Tags t on t.ID=btl.TAG 
where t.TAGNAME='fiction';
```

Caveat: if all tables are large, you have to make sure that the fields mentioned in JOIN are keys (indexes).

Comment: Your first join is wrong. There's no direct relation between Books and Tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two joins:

```
select
    books.title

from
    books

inner join
    books_tag_link on
        books_tag_link.book = book.id

inner join
    tags on
        tags.id = books_tag_link.tag

where
    tag.tagname = 'fiction'
```